# How to make my lightswitch application available to the internet?

Tags: networking, visual-studio-lightswitch

I recently finished a lightswitch application. It's a simple POS app. I managed to install it to my own webserver created  in vmware running windows 2008 im using IIS7. I can now hit the site in my localhost. My question now is how do I make the website available on the internet? I did a lot of reading but no luck. I already have a domain name registered from godaddy. I already tried opening port 80 of my router but it's not working(I dont know how to troubleshoot that though I only check at http://www.yougetsignal.com). I feel like this is becoming complex for me due to the fact that I'm using a virtual machine.

Can anyone give me basic step by step instructions on how to accomplish this? Or provide an alternative on how I can accomplish this easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have a Static IP on your router. (Public IP)
2. Make sure you have a Static IP on your server. (Local IP)
3. Register your domain name.
4. Configure your domain name's DNS servers.
5. Configure your DNS servers to point to your router's Static Public IP.
6. Configure port forwarding on your router so that connections on port 80 (from the internet) are forwarded to your server. (Local IP)
7. Open port 80 on your Server.  There should already be a firewall rule for it, just enable it.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks Kris! That helped me a lot. I now have access to my application! :)